# El método "equalsIgnoreCase" , "nextLine()" o los objetos de tipo Scanner ¿No aceptan caracteres que no sean del lenguaje inglés?

Tags: java

cree un programa en donde debo ingresar desde el teclado el nombre de una materia y me tiene que retornar la calificación en la pantalla,
funciona bien al ingresar matematicas, biologia e ingles, pero al ingresar
desde el teclado la palabra español , el programa no me retorna nada,
debe ser por que la palabra tiene una "ñ", y debe tener algun problema
con algun metodo o por ser objeto de tipo Scanner, detallo más ampliamente el
problema en los comentarios del código Java

```
package Aborto;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class if_else_aborto{

public static void main (String args[]){


//calificaciones de las materias guardadas

int mate = 10,  esp = 5, ing = 9, bio = 8;

// caracteres de las materias
String matematicas = "matematicas", español = "español", ingles = "ingles", 
       biologia = "biologia"; 


// para la entrada
String materia;
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);


//Aquí me pide la calificación 
 System.out.print("De que materia quieres tu calificación : ");
  materia = entrada.nextLine();


//Parte de las condicionales "if else"
  if( materia.equalsIgnoreCase(matematicas)){
    System.out.println("sacaste " + mate + " en matematicas" ); 
  }

/*Es en esta condicional en donde no imprime el mensaje , aqui es donde
tengo duda, por que no se si es el método "equalsIgnoreCase()" ,"nextLine()"
o los objetos de tipo Scanner los que no aceptan caracteres fuera del lenguaje 
ingles, por que al poner español sin la letra "ñ" (espanol)
el programa funciona correctamente , pero como ya les había dicho, al escribir "español" con "ñ", 
el programa no me retorna nada en la pantalla */    
  else if(materia.equalsIgnoreCase(español)){
  System.out.println("sacaste " + esp + " en español");
  }


//ya las de abajo funcionan correctamente   
  else if( materia.equalsIgnoreCase(ingles)){
  System.out.println("sacaste " + ing + " en ingles");
  }

  else if( materia.equalsIgnoreCase(biologia)){
  System.out.println("sacaste " + bio + " en biologia");
}  
 }
}
```

Comment: en la declaración de la materia `español = "espanól"` no hay una `ñ` es una `n` y la `o` tiene tilde, así lo esta ingresando??

Comment: jaja perdon , asi no queria subir el codigo, supon que los declare de la siguinete manera :  String español = español . Con ñ

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo de los datos que introduces antes de introducir español? Acabo de probar y a mi me funciona.

Comment: no se introduce ningún dato antes, solo a la primera te pregunta de que materia quieres saber tu calificación, escribis una de las cuatro opciones y se imprime en pantalla la calificación, en todas funciona excepto en español

Comment: osea escribes "espanol" no pasa nada, pero si escribes "español" con "ñ", ahi si que hay un problema

Comment: ¿lo ejecutas desde el IDE o por la linea de comandos?

Comment: @OscarIvanLopez define "entrada" de esta forma : Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in, "ISO-8859-1");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Scanner con caracteres acentuados.**

En este caso al declarar el `Scanner`, por default no puede interpretar acentos o tildes del idioma español, por ejemplo si escribes :

```
español
```

lo que almacenará de una forma no adecuada:

```
espa�ol
```

debido a esto no podrías realizar la comparación.

Para solucionar este problema simplemente define como codificación  "ISO-8859-1",

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in, "ISO-8859-1");
```

esto sera suficiente para que pueda reconocer los acentos y puedas realizar la comparación sin problema.

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in, "ISO-8859-1");
System.out.print("De que materia quieres tu calificación : ");
materia = entrada.nextLine();
...
...
if(materia.equalsIgnoreCase(español)){
  System.out.println("sacaste " + esp + " en español");
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda brou :D, ahora funciona correctamente el programa

Comment: Excelente @OscarIvanLopez , saludos.